# Windows Photo Viewer can't navigate between images when viewed at actual size

Tags: windows-10, windows-photo-viewer

I have a folder of images that I want to be able to navigate through in Windows Photo Viewer. These images are large and don't fully fit on my screen at actual size.

If I open any image in the folder, Photo Viewer displays it scaled down to fit and with back/forward arrows on either side for navigation. I can click the arrows or use the left and right arrow keys on the keyboard to navigate - so far so good.

The problem is that if I right-click the image and choose "View actual size," then the navigation arrows disappear. They're not just hidden, they're really gone - even the left and right arrow keys stop working. If I right-click again and go back to "Zoom to fit," then the arrows come back and the keyboard arrow keys work again.

So in other words, if I want to go through a folder of images at full size, I have to toggle from "zoom to fit" (the initial view) to "view actual size" and then back to "zoom to fit" to get the navigation arrows to reappear, for every single image!

I can't imagine why this would be intentional or desirable. Is there really no way to simply navigate through a folder of images at full size?

Comment: *"I can't imagine why this would be intentional or desirable."*  It makes sense to me.  If you want to quickly navigate through a folder of pictures, the arrows are readily available.  On the other hand, if you want to scrutinize a particular photo at its native resolution you can stop and zoom in accordingly.

Comment: @Run5k Actually, if you have a big enough screen, all the photos might appear too small and require zooming to fit.  In this case, it's *extremely* annoying to have to keep switching into zoom to fit mode, then back out before one can navigate to the next image.

Comment: I have a folder of 218 images that I have to go through and in about 80% of cases I need to scrutinize details in each one. It's pretty annoying when those forward arrows are hidden!

Answer (score 0):

This is a really annoying issue. There is no solution but I could create a workaround: I powershell script to make the many steps I would have to do manually on an automated way. Ex: Press "arrow right": first press esc, then arrow right, then zoom in, the scroll up. See:

```
#Run this command line on a command prompt, powershell 7 required. Replace -File param with the path of the file
#pwsh -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Workspace\repos\test2\pdf-utilities\sendkeys.ps1 -WindowTitle Archie
param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$WindowTitle)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
$SendKeys = [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]
$Interaction = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]

while ($true) {
    $key = [System.Console]::ReadKey($true).key
    if ($key -eq 'e') {
        Exit
    }

    $Interaction::AppActivate($WindowTitle)
    Start-Sleep 0.1
    
    if ($key -eq 'LeftArrow' -Or $key -eq 'RightArrow') {
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{ESC}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait($key -eq 'LeftArrow' ? "{LEFT}" : "{RIGHT}")
        $key = 'x'
    }
    
    if ($key -eq 'x') {
        $SendKeys::SendWait("^=")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("^=")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("^=")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("^=")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("^=")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("^=")
        $key = 'UpArrow'
    }
    
    if ($key -eq 'UpArrow' -Or $key -eq 'DownArrow') {
        $arrow = $key -eq 'UpArrow' ? 'UP' : 'DOWN'
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
    }

    if ($key -eq 'PageUp' -Or $key -eq 'PageDown') {
        $arrow = $key -eq 'PageUp' ? 'UP' : 'DOWN'
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
        $SendKeys::SendWait("{$arrow}")
    }
    
    $SendKeys::Flush()
    $Interaction::AppActivate('Command')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution:

1. You are not being forced to use the Windows Viewer (hopefully).
2. Use a different viewer e. g. ImageGlass or IrfanView or any other for that matter
3. Customize the keyboard shortcuts on those according to your preference.
4. As a bonus some image viewers allow you to open images at full resolution.

Cheers!